# Clean way to persist an enum field with JDBI3?

Tags: java, enums, dropwizard, jdbi

I'm building an app with Dropwizard, and I want one of my persisted entities to have an enum field:

```
class DogEntity {
  public String name;
  public DogType type;
}

enum DogType {
  HUSKY("canis lupus familiaris"),
  LAB("canus familiaris")

  private final String value;

  Type(String value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

How can I get JDBI to persist the *value* of the DogType to the database, as opposed to the name or ordinal?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, Jdbi 3 support Enum as argument type, but it is stored as the enum value’s name.

But, you can use [Custom Arguments](http://jdbi.org/#_custom_arguments) for data types that are not natively supported by Jdbi.

Example for Argument Factory for your case would be:

```java
public class DogTypeArgumentFactory extends AbstractArgumentFactory<DogType> {

public DogTypeArgumentFactory() {
    super(Types.VARCHAR);
}

@Override
public Argument build(final DogType dogType, ConfigRegistry config) {
    return new Argument() {
        @Override
        public void apply(int position, PreparedStatement statement, StatementContext ctx) throws SQLException {
            statement.setString(position, dogType.getValue());
        }
    };
  }  
}
```

Comment: I would call persisting enum names a bad practice, because eventually someone will want to change it.

Is there an annotation for that UuidArgument binding? The CAST in the SQL is spooky. Is that just to help JDBI or is it a DB operation?

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite get the last thing. About which CAST are we talking about?

Comment: As for UUID and annotation, there is no need for annotation, Jdbi supports UUID out of the box as Argument Type. More on supported types [here](http://jdbi.org/#_supported_argument_types)

Comment: The Custom Arguments link uses a SQL statement with "CAST" in it.

My code doesn't use the handle directly, it uses annotations for bindings and queries. It's just cleaner.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "CAST", but I think I am a little bit more clear what were you talking about. You can just create argument factory and extend `AbstractArgumentFactory`, then register it. When you register an ArgumentFactory, the registration is stored in an Arguments instance held by Jdbi. Arguments is a configuration class which stores all registered argument factories (including the factories for built-in arguments). 
Later, when the statement is executed, each Argument located during binding is applied to the JDBC PreparedStatement.

Comment: OK, I updated the answer with example of Argument Factory for your case

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I wound up with:

```
public class DogTypeArgumentFactory implements ArgumentFactory {
  @Override
  public Optional<Argument> build(Type type, Object value, ConfigRegistry config) {
    if (value == null || !type.getTypeName().equals(DogType.class.getName())) {
      return Optional.empty();
    }

    return Optional.of(new DogTypeArgument((DogType) value));
  }


  private class DogTypeArgument implements Argument {
    private final DogType value;

    private DogTypeArgument(DogType value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(
        int position, PreparedStatement statement, StatementContext context) throws SQLException {

      statement.setInt(position, value.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

It feels a bit long-winded if I need to use it for every persistent enum value...I suppose they could all share a common interface, if that works.